# Create Formik Form From List of Fields

Tags: node.js, reactjs, formik

Digging Formik, but despite the streamlining, it's still tedious to build the form from a list of database fields (say 50-100).

Has anyone created a generator yet that builds the code for a Formik form from a list, or is there a helper that can create a Formik form from a JSON object?

Comment: You could try implementing yourself, that would be fun and you would learn alot.

Comment: @Vencovsky Obviously, yes, but to do that if one exists would be silly - thus I ask here.